# Disk full after deleting large files and rebooting

Tags: disk-usage, ext4, disk

I accidentally filled up my hard drive and I cannot recover from it.

I've deleted several Gigabyte of files, but the `df` command still shows that the disk is full, and even a simple `echo hello > aFile` results in the error `write error: No space left on disk`.
Here is the command output of the relevant line of `df`

```
Filesystem                Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root 441G 421G     0 100% /
```

From reading other similar questions/answers, I'm aware that [Linux does not delete files that are part of active processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218406/disk-still-full-after-deleting-some-files), even if they disappear from the file system. Most accepted solutions involve restarting the process holding the file open or rebooting the computer. I've rebooted several times after deleting files and I still have the same issue. [Using all the inodes can result in a similar error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218406/disk-still-full-after-deleting-some-files) but my inode use is 18%.

I'm also aware that the [system reserves space for the root user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197798/96503) and that `df` does not report this accurately. In my case, the difference between disk size and used is 20G. I can write files as root, but I don't know how to make use of this fact.

In case it's relevant, my system is set up to use KDE on Linux Mint. I only have one LUKS-encrypted ext4 partition.

The disk space being full stops the X server starting as the system cannot write to a lock file so I end up having three options:

1. log in via TTY1 into a terminal,
2. `sudo startx` which launches a Cinnamon graphical environment,
3. Boot a live CD/USB.

What should I do to recover my disk space?

Comment: Boot in recovery mode/from LiveCD, `e2fsck /dev/device`, check again. Lastly, are you sure you're in the right directory? You could be trying to create a file in another directory which e.g. belongs to a full partition/mount point.

Comment: I will try a LiveCD in a few minutes. Yes, I'm sure I'm in the right directory. In addition, `startx` run as a normal user from TTY1 also cannot write to various files in /tmp

Comment: might be a long shot but have you tried trimming your disks with `fstrim`? For example run `fstrim -av` and see if there will be a difference in size

Comment: Using KDE ? Hmmm… how did you delete the files ? (moved to trash or actually deleted)

Comment: @MC68020 I deleted the files using the command `rm` in a terminal. They shouldn't be clogging the trash.

Comment: @Alex I tried `fstrim`. It reported that it trimmed 20GiB but `df` still shows 0 available.

Comment: Did you reboot in order to have the LVM remounted after trim?

Comment: you can disable ext4 root reserve with `tune2fs -m 0`. alternatively set it to 1% instead of the default 5% to leave a (smaller) reserve for root. in the long term you'll just have to provide more storage space if you're that close to full capacity… that or use `ncdu` and similar to identify space hogs (log files, caches, ...)

Comment: @frostschutz he's got 420GB of free space. That's over 95%.

Comment: @Alex, I didn't realise I had to, but I have now and it's not made any difference.

Comment: Have you got a lot of file/directories in /lost+found?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I've been trying to work on your suggestion, but I am struggling as the drive is encrypted. I can decrypt the drive using `cryptsetup` but even if I don't mount it `e2fsck` says the volume is in use so can't run. If I don't decrypt it `e2fsk` doesn't recognise it as ext4. Any suggestions?

Comment: @frostschutz Your suggestion worked. I only reduced it by 1% but that let me log in graphically. Further deletions then started showing as available space in the output of `df`. If you submit an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Mehmet 5% of 441G is around 22G, while 1% is only around 4.5GB, I second  
frostschutz's suggestion to reduce root's reserve to 1%.   BTW, if you haven't already done so, you can probably regain a lot of space by deleting packages downloaded by your package manager.  eg. Debian (etc) store downloaded .deb files in /var/cache/apt/archives. You can delete them with `apt-get clean`. Other distros will differ.  Also, /var/cache and /var/log are good places to search for stuff that can be deleted.  Also worth considering: switch to btrfs or zfs or some other fs with transparent compression.

Answer (score 1):

A solution without `tune2fs`.

> I'm also aware that the system reserves space for the root user […]. I can write files as root, but I don't know how to make use of this fact.

The default 5% does not mean "5% for root", it means "the last 5% for root, regardless of who uses the rest". So if root manages to use up at least some of these 5% then you need to remove enough files (root's or anyone's files) to  actually raise the free space (available to root) above the threshold; only then a non-root user will see space left and be able to use it.

What you deleted apparently was not enough. Delete more.

Note if you delete regular users' files and root takes the reserved space again, and you delete some other regular users' files, then the root will be able to take the resulting free space as reserved space *again*. It doesn't matter root used the reserved space in the past and has freed nothing since.

I wrote "5%" because it's the default. The conclusions apply to any non-zero reserved space.

Comment: Note: a solution with `tune2fs` may be better in some cases, but I don't want to steal it from the user who mentioned it in comments. Hopefully the user will post an answer.

Comment: This is very helpful for understanding *why* deleting a significant amount of files wasn't enough to solve the issue. I used the `tune2fs` solution to regain some control but then cleared out even more files.